# ORA-02270 Referencing a foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sqlplus

I have **1st table**:

```
CREATE TABLE HEAD (
Code int, 
Name varchar(99),
HType char(1),
HDate date, 
OpBal number(10),

CONSTRAINT pk_head PRIMARY KEY (Code, Name));
```

and **2nd table**:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBHEAD (
    HCode int,
    SubCode int,
    Name varchar(99),
    SDate date, 
    OpBal number(10),

    CONSTRAINT fk_subhead FOREIGN KEY (HCode) REFERENCES HEAD(Code),
    CONSTRAINT pk_subhead PRIMARY KEY (Hcode, SubCode));
```

Now when I run the script, I get:

> CONSTRAINT fk_subhead FOREIGN KEY (HCode) REFERENCES HEAD(Code),
>
> ERROR at line 7:
>
> ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

I have been looking around trying to figure out what's wrong and I think it has something to do with parent table constraint but I am totally stumped on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your foreign key is not referencing the entire primary key from `HEAD`.

So you either need to change the foreign key (to include name in there) or change the primary key of `HEAD` to exclude name there.

So either change

```
CONSTRAINT pk_head PRIMARY KEY (Code, Name));
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT pk_head PRIMARY KEY (Code));
```

or change

```
CONSTRAINT fk_subhead FOREIGN KEY (HCode) REFERENCES HEAD(Code)
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT fk_subhead FOREIGN KEY (HCode, Name) REFERENCES HEAD(Code, Name)
```